# How to add all sites from a specific domain into Opera GX's dark mode?

Tags: browser-addons, opera, dark-mode

I recently installed Opera GX and learned about their dark mode extension, and I tried it on Stack Exchange, specifically Seasoned Advice:

[image: Seasoned Advice screenshot]

So there's a configuration set where I can choose which sites can have dark mode enabled without needing to turn on the extension manually. I already set the following domains that comes from Stack Exchange, except if I only add `stackexchange.com`, only Stack Exchange gets dark mode, but not sites that also happen to have the same domain which is `*.stackexchange.com`.

How to get all sites with `*.stackexchange.com` have dark mode without adding them one by one? `*.stackexchange.com` doesn't work.